what is the name of this representation of graphs
I try to encode undirected unnamed graph as efficient as possible and come up with this representation (I wonder if it already have a name):
For a graph with k vertices: at each vertices count its edges as a number n, and then order those n from smallest to largest:
n1 n2 n3 n4 ... nk
This encoding work for several small graph that I try, but I don't know if it will work for bigger graph or not.
After searching the internet I can not find the name of this representation so I ask here.
More example:
Assume there 4 vertices {0, 1, 2, 3} this representation will map:
{0, 1, 2, 3} -> 0000
{{0, 1}, 2, 3} -> 0011
{{0, 1}, {2, 3}} -> 1111
{{0, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}} -> 1122
{{0, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}} -> 1223

Please use MathJax

Each edge will connect exactly two vertices. What do you mean by counting the vertices at each edge?

@JohnDouma I mixed up between vertices and edges. Im so sorry.

Perhaps you can add examples for all 11 graphs with 4 vertices?
